# How to check a node contains empty string or space or null in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to check using xpath an node in the xml contains empty string/spaces. What is the xpath expression i need to use?

eg:

```
 <p:insert_acc_data_file xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<p:Id>123</p:Id>
<p:Name></p:pName>
</p:insert_acc_data_file>
```

How to check the Name node is empty or containing space values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By checking if *a node is empty* I guess you mean *has no child element (text or node)*.

Checking if a node contains only space values can be done using `normalize-space()` function.

I suggest you use this condition: `not(./*) and normalize-space(.)=""`, i.e.

- does not have child nodes
- and if it has child text element, the whitespace normalized string representation of the node is an empty string

Comment: If I am not mistaking * matches elements, but not text nodes. So I think you should use not(./node()) if you want to know your element doesn't have chlid nodes no matter the type

Comment: @EduardDrenth, I believe you are correct, `*` will match elements. I think my query is correct for the case of `<p:Name>      </p:pName>` (an element with a text node with only whitespace). My comments is probably wrong here, where "does not have child nodes" should read "does not have child elements"

Comment: It is also useful to strip &nbsp; characters when looking for whitespace. e.g.
`'//p[not(./*) and normalize-space(translate(., "", " "))=""]'` or `'//p[not(./*) and normalize-space(translate(., "&#160;", " "))=""]'` (the former is the UTF8 character 0xA0.)

Answer (score 0):

**For both mentioned type.**

```
<Employee/>
<Employee></Employee>
```

**Below code will work**

```
string(your_node_xpath) != ''
```